# Opening custom editor when a file contains an specific text (Eclipse RCP)

Tags: java, editor, eclipse-rcp

I'm creating some editors for a simple project, so far everything is fine, except that at the moment, my editors are bound to an specific file extension, for example, one editor opens xml files, other editor opens .properties files, and that's fine for now, but what I need to do, is to launch the editor just when the opened file contains an specific string. I'm actually trying to launch my editors when the project version is "3.4", so, when the files contains something like this: `version="3.4"`, it should launch my editor, is there a way to do that, or is there a better way to to that?

Notice that the project version is specified in a project facet as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `describer` element as a child of `content-type` which defines a class to be called which can check if a file is valid for this content type.

```xml
<content-type id="customType"
   base-type="org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facesconfig.facesConfigFile"
   file-extensions="xml">
  <describer class="package.MyDescriber"/>
</content-type>
```

The class must implement `IContentDescriber` (or `ITextContentDescriber`).

The method:

```java
public int describe(InputStream contents, IContentDescription description)
```

is called to check the contents. Return `VALID` if it is OK, `INVALID` if not.

You can also support other properties for the file (such as determining the character encoding) if needed.

More information in the Eclipse help on the extension point.